# unter dem Regen oder in dem Regen laufen?

Tags: preposition, noun, expression

I wonder the positions of people, they walk *unter dem Regen* or *in dem Regen* or *mit dem Regen*? Following expressions are possible?

> Der romantischste Moment für mich ist das Zufußgehen in dem Regen.
>
> Das Spiel ist unter dem Regen gespielt worden.
>
> Es ist schwer, unter dem Regen zu arbeiten.

Comment: *Zufußgehen* seems a bit odd. I would replace it by *Spazierengehen* (stroll), if not something like a barefooted walk was intended.

Comment: Assume that you have to reach a point on the world,you are in hurry, would you use after all "spazierengehen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Germany you say *bei Regen* or *im Regen* (*in dem* is shortened to *im*) [(Duden)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Regen_Niederschlag). I tried to find a explanation to distinguish the two options, but so far I haven’t found one.
I would say: *im Regen* emphasized the interaction with rain (becoming wet, hear the sound of the raindrops etc). *Bei Regen* is more neutral, expressing that something happends during rainfall.

> Ich gehe gerne im Regen joggen.

means that I love to run (e.g. because I like the feeling of the raindrops on my skin or the sound of the drops on my umbrella).

> Ich gehe auch bei Regen joggen.

I go running also when it rains (but it is not special for me).

---

Concerning your examples, I would say:

> Der romantischste Moment für mich ist das Spazierengehen im Regen.

(*zu Fuß gehen* just means to go, that is hardly romantic)

> Das Spiel ist im Regen gespielt worden. *or* Es hat während des Spiels geregnet.
>
> Es ist schwer im Regen zu arbeiten. (When you work outside and everything is wet and slippy) *or*
>
> Es ist schwer bei Regen zu arbeiten. (When you work in an office, but you are distracted because you would love to be outside)

Answer (score 6):

For these activities in your list of example it should be *im Regen*. Note also the spelling.

Comment: *Bei Regen* is another common option...

Comment: This should have been an edit to the OP, not an answer.

Comment: Why "bei Regen" instead "beim Regen"?

Comment: @user unknown, do you have an example? Because I would say "unter Regen" is always wrong.

Comment: @Iris: Da ich keins finde lösche ich meinen Kommentar unauffällig in 3...2..1.. >-<